# Using ECDH with OpenSSL

Tags: openssl

Is there anyway to generate, sign, verify, and use ECDH keys with OpenSSL on the command line? I'm somewhat familiar with the normal Diffie-Hellman facilities that the utility provides, but I cannot see anything about the elliptic curve variant.

Answer (score 0):

For signatures you would need [ECDSA, not ECDH](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/12829/4941) – the latter is a *key exchange* algorithm, mostly used for encryption.

There's `openssl dgst -sign`:

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -sign <priv_key_file> -out <sig_file> <data_file>
```

There's also `openssl pkeyutl`:

```
openssl pkeyutl -sign -in <data_file> -inkey <priv_key_file> -out <sig_file>
```

(Note that `pkeyutl` only supports SHA1 with ECDSA; `-pkeyopt digest:sha256` is only accepted with RSA keys. Meanwhile `dgst` seems to work with all digests, but I'm not 100% sure about it.)

Other tools exist, such as [ecdsatool](https://github.com/kaniini/ecdsatool).

If you have an ECDSA-based X.509 *certificate*, you would want `openssl cms`.

Comment: No, no, no, no, no. *Signing* an ECDH public key.

Comment: Signing the key _itself_?

Comment: Yes, the elliptic curve Diffie-Hellman public key file so it can be verified by the receiving party.

Comment: Well, you sign DH keys just like you would sign any other data. And _that_ depends on what kind of _signing_ key you have...

Comment: What is `openssl cms` used for?